# Focus on Parent window in jquery

Tags: jquery

How to get focus on parent window in jquery , javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).click(function(){
                var a =  $('#dialog').clone().html();
                var yourDOCTYPE = "<!DOCTYPE html>"; 
                var printPreview = window.open('about:blank', 'print_preview', "menubar=1,resizable=1,width=1024,height=600");
                var printDocument = printPreview.document;
                printDocument.open();   
                printDocument.write(yourDOCTYPE+    "<html>"+ a + "</html>");
                printPreview.focus();
                $(this).focus();
                }); 
        });
```